# deployed php app can have more than ten thousand hits per day

Tags: google-compute-engine

After deploying my PHP application to google cloud platform, it may get around 10000 hits simultaneously, so, Can the platform handle such no. of request at time.

Thanks

Comment: Your title says "per day", but your question says "simultaneously".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you'd need more than one server to handle 10k requests/second, but both the VM (Compute Engine) and App Engine platforms have [scaled to over 1M requests/second](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/11/compute-engine-load-balancing-hits-1-million-requests-per-second.html).

I don't have a link for App Engine, but it's possible to handle that level of traffic -- [see this article about Snapchat for an example](https://gigaom.com/2013/05/07/snapchats-act-of-faith-in-building-on-google-compute-engine/)